# MySQL - returning data from one table which match multiple combinations of data in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called `meta_data` with the following structure

```
id, fk_id, label, data
```

where fk_id links to another table - `books`

The `meta_data` table has entries such as:

```
|id|fk_id|label|data   |
|--|-----|-----|-------|
|1 |1    |pages|10     |
|2 |2    |pages|10     |
|3 |1    |pub  |smith  |
|4 |3    |pub  |smith  |
```

I want to do a select on `books` where there is entries in `meta_data` which match a number of parameters e.g. `pages = 10` AND `pub = smith`.

So using the example above I would get the entry back in the `books` table with id 1 (2 and 3 would not be included as although they match one of the criteria, they don't match both).

This query would also need to be dynamic so I could query on 1 or more label/data combinations in the `meta_data` table e.g. I am querying on 2 combinations in the example above but might want to query on 4 or 5.

Also there might me multiple entries in the `meta_data` table with the same label but different data values.  e.g. there could be another row:

```
|5 |1    |pub  |jones  |
```

Can anyone give me an example of how this query should look using MySQL?

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE books; SHOW CREATE TABLE meta_data;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for the condition you specified in the question. If you want the condition to be more dynamic you should build the query dynamically in the application.

```
Select b.book_name from books b, meta_data m, meta_data md
WHERE b.id = m.fk_id and b.id = md.fk_id 
and m.label ='pages' and m.data = 10 
and md.label ='pub' and md.data='smith'
```